# Tandem (Guardian OS) scheduler

Tags: tandem

I've an assignment to run the command on Tandem by periodic time

I've work on Windows and Unix before and know that OS have there own schedule task but I cannot find one on Tandem

I've ask HPE support they mention that I must by a tool name "NetBatch" to make a schedule

now I come up with a solution by create job to run command like this

1.Run command
2.Wait time
2.Run command
4.Wait time

Have anyone here have experience with schedule task on Tandem please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tacl script with a loop, add all commands you want in that loop with `#DELAY` at end of the loop so that the script waits till next iteration of loop

To add persistance to your script you can configure it under pathway as below:

```
RESET SERVER
SET SERVER MAXSERVERS 1
SET SERVER NUMSTATIC 1
SET SERVER PROGRAM $SYSTEM.SYS01.TACL
SET SERVER TMF OFF
SET SERVER IN $receive
SET SERVER ASSIGN TACLCSTM, $vol.subvol.taclin ==The script that you want to execute
SET SERVER OUT $vol.subvol.uroutfil ==Output printed from your script
ADD SERVER mytacl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to from Guardian to OSS and use crontab on tandem OSS

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert wait between two [tandem advanced command language] TACL commands by entering some other command or using something from history like opening files.

`dsply pr, prc310
cmprfile -28, today, range
cmprtime 00,23
dsply pr, prc310, diff`

NOTE: The last code executes with a time difference of 3 seconds.

This will surely delay the simultaneous command from being executed at the same time.

I also faced the same situation, and followed above hack to get it rectified.